# Setfocus to the searchbox in a tlistview

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle, tlistview

I am working in Seattle, writing a FM application for windows only.

I have A tlistview on my form and have it populated with data.

I have the search option turned on.

How do I programmatically set focus to the search box?

How do I increase the size and font size of the search box?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The searchbox is not intended to be accessed programmatically except for setting it visible and to fire event when changed. Otherwise it is intended to be accessed only by the user.
Therefore, access is a little bit involved. However, the [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListView.TListView.OnSearchChange) of the `OnSearchChange` event inspired the following answer:

```
uses ..., FMX.SearchBox;

type
  TForm17 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    ...
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    sb: TSearchBox; // a local reference
  ...
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm17.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(sb) then
    sb.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TForm17.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  ListView1.SearchVisible := True; // or set in the Object Inspector at design time
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Controls.Count-1 do
    if ListView1.Controls[I].ClassType = TSearchBox then
    begin
      sb := TSearchBox(ListView1.Controls[i]);
      Break;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm17.ListView1SearchChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(sb) then
    Label1.Text := sb.Text;
end;
```

At form creation we search the SearchBox control and if found we store a reference to it in the `sb: TSearchBox;` field. Then access is quite straightforward.

Comment: I keep warning people not to use SetFocus without CanFocus! You do this in your code. You need to call first CanFocus otherwise your code could raise an exception if the control cannot be focused. But even that will not work in all cases. CanFocus is  **BROKEN**  (or incomplete in Delphi). Please check this article on how to [fix it](https://gabrielmoraru.com/setfocus-is-broken-in-delphi/)

Comment: @GabrielMoraru It may well be that you are on to something, but I would like to have more info on it, **as I cannot reproduce what you claim**. First of all: Are you talking about **VCL** or **FMX** or **both**? Secondly, which version of Delphi do you refer to? Then, in **which specific situation** can the call to `SetFocus()` (without an explicit call to `CanFocus()`) cause an exception, and **which one**?

Comment: Hi. The article I linked to should explain what is wrong with the CanFocus. Please write me if you think there is something wrong with the code, or you can still not reproduce it.